Get rid of a circular reference on complex entities relations (Symfony 6.4)
I have a circular reference error in my app, when i want of normalize an object width ObjectNormalizer and Serializer, that I can't get rid of.
I've done that several times but this app is more complex than the others that I've codded.
My app is a magazine backend for contents writing. To simplify, let's say the contents can be Article, Groupement (group of contents) or Diaporama (slideshow).
Where it become more complex is that, since all contents have several fields in common, all contents entities is related to a mother entity GlobalContent in a oneToOne relation.
Every content (except Groupement) can be related to 0-n Groupement. So, if you get it, a GlobalContent have two relations Groupement: a GlobalContent can BE a Groupement (OneToOne nullable relation) and a GlobalContent can BELONG TO 0-n Groupement

(From there, to simplify, since every entity is related to a single GlobalContent entity, I'll name the two entities in a single name. Ex: GlobalContent-Article)
So the GlobalContent-Article "This summer's pie eating contest" is related to the GlobalContent-Groupement "This summer fun activities" (which is related to several other contents, which are related to several other GlobalContent-Groupement). But thit GlobalContent-Article is also related to other GlobalContent-Groupement, which are related to other contents and so.

GlobalContent Entity

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\MiniSite;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PhpParser\Node\Expr\Cast\Bool_;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: 'App\Repository\GlobalContentRepository')]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class GlobalContent
{
    use Timestamps;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $main_titre;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $date_publication;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $date_maj;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Article', mappedBy: 'global_content', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $article;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Diaporama', mappedBy: 'global_content', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $diaporama;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Groupement', mappedBy: 'global_content', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $groupement;

    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'global_content_groupement')]
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Groupement', inversedBy: 'all_global_contents')]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $all_groupements;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Theme::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $mainTheme;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Image')]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $image;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json', nullable: true)]
    private $published = null;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->all_groupements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->main_titre;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getMainTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->main_titre;
    }

    public function setMainTitre(string $main_titre): self
    {
        $this->main_titre = $main_titre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatePublication(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_publication;
    }

    public function setDatePublication(\DateTimeInterface $date_publication): self
    {
        $this->date_publication = $date_publication;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateMaj(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date_maj;
    }

    public function setDateMaj(?\DateTimeInterface $date_maj): self
    {
        $this->date_maj = $date_maj;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArticle(): ?Article
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    public function setArticle(?Article $article): self
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($article->getGlobalContent() !== $this) {
            $article->setGlobalContent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDiaporama(): ?Diaporama
    {
        return $this->diaporama;
    }

    public function setDiaporama(?Diaporama $diaporama): self
    {
        $this->diaporama = $diaporama;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroupement(): ?Groupement
    {
        return $this->groupement;
    }

    public function setGroupement(?Groupement $groupement): self
    {
        $this->groupement = $groupement;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Groupement[]
     */
    public function getAllGroupements(): Collection
    {
        return $this->all_groupements;
    }

    public function addAllGroupement(Groupement $groupement): self
    {
        // $groupement->addGlobalContent($this); // synchronously updating inverse side
        if (!$this->all_groupements->contains($groupement)) {
            $this->all_groupements[] = $groupement;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAllGroupement(Groupement $groupement): self
    {
        if ($this->all_groupements->contains($groupement)) {
            $this->all_groupements->removeElement($groupement);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMainTheme(): ?Theme
    {
        return $this->mainTheme;
    }

    public function setMainTheme(?Theme $mainTheme): self
    {
        $this->mainTheme = $mainTheme;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?Image
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(?Image $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPublished(): ?array
    {
        return $this->published;
    }

    public function setPublished(?array $published): self
    {
        $this->published = $published;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType(): string
    {
        if(!is_null($this->getArticle())){
            $type = "Article";
        } else if(!is_null($this->getDiaporama())){
            $type = "Diaporama";            
        } else if(!is_null($this->getGroupement())){
            $type = "Groupement";
        } else{
            $type = "Inconnu";            
        }

        return $type;
    }

    public function getSlugType(): string
    {
        if($this->getType() == "Article"){
            $slug = "article";
        } else if($this->getType() == "Diaporama"){
            $slug = "diaporama";
        } else if($this->getType() == "Groupement"){
            $slug = "groupement";
        } else{
            $slug = "inconnu";
        }

        return $slug;
    }
}

Groupement Entity
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: 'App\Repository\GroupementRepository')]
class Groupement
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $texte;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\GlobalContent', inversedBy: 'groupement', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $global_content;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\GlobalContent', mappedBy: 'all_groupements')]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $all_global_contents;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->all_global_contents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->global_content;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTexte(): ?string
    {
        return $this->texte;
    }

    public function setTexte(?string $texte): self
    {
        $this->texte = $texte;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGlobalContent(): ?GlobalContent
    {
        return $this->global_content;
    }

    public function setGlobalContent(GlobalContent $global_content): self
    {
        $this->global_content = $global_content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|GlobalContent[]
     */
    public function getAllGlobalContents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->all_global_contents;
    }

    public function addAllGlobalContent(GlobalContent $global_content): self
    {
        // $global_content->addGroupement($this); // synchronously updating inverse side
        if (!$this->all_global_contents->contains($global_content)) {
            $this->all_global_contents[] = $global_content;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAllGlobalContent(GlobalContent $global_content): self
    {
        if ($this->all_global_contents->contains($global_content)) {
            $this->all_global_contents->removeElement($global_content);
        }
        return $this;
    }


}


Article Entity
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: 'App\Repository\ArticleRepository')]
class Article
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:contents'])]
    private $main_content;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\GlobalContent', inversedBy: 'article', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $global_content;




    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getMainContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->main_content;
    }

    public function setMainContent(?string $main_content): self
    {
        $this->main_content = $main_content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGlobalContent(): ?GlobalContent
    {
        return $this->global_content;
    }

    public function setGlobalContent(GlobalContent $global_content): self
    {
        $this->global_content = $global_content;

        return $this;
    }


}

I've tried to set a MaxDepth on every GlobalContent and Groupement declaration of the entities (and set AbstractObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH => true. But I have seen no difference.
I've also tried to set AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {return $object->__toString();} but doing this just create a memory leak, and create the error, even though I have set my PHP's memory_limit to 2048M.
(I also tried to call getId() instead of __toString() width the same result)

Error: Allowed memory size of 2516582400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 275584840 bytes)

Here is the code I call:
$defaultContext = [
    AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
        return $object->__toString();
    },
    AbstractObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH => true,
    'groups' => 'read:contents',
];

$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AttributeLoader());
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);
$serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer]);

$contentJSON = $serializer->normalize($global_content, 'json', $defaultContext);

The MaxDepth thing was promising because I dont need the whole thing in my JSON. But I didn't make it work.

Can't you just ignore some fields to break the cycles during serialization?

I am agree with @Olivier, how i solved the this week issue return $this->normalizer->normalize($actor, 'json', [
AbstractNormalizer::ATTRIBUTES => [
'id',
'externalId',
'code',
'name',
'country',
]
]);

That was the problem: I need all the fields.

Nevermind...
The error comes from the fact that both GlobalContent.allGroupements AND Groupement.AllGlobalContents are used. I simply put them in two differents groups.
In GlobalContent entity
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'global_content_groupement')]
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\Groupement', inversedBy: 'all_global_contents')]
    #[Groups(['read:not-groupements'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $all_groupements;

In Groupement entity
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: 'App\Entity\GlobalContent', mappedBy: 'all_groupements')]
    #[Groups(['read:groupements'])]
    #[MaxDepth(1)]
    private $all_global_contents;

In the controller
    $groups = ['read:contents'];
    if($global_content->getType() == 'Groupement'){
        array_push($groups, 'read:groupements');
    } else{
        array_push($groups, 'read:not-groupements');
    }

    $defaultContext = [
        AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
            return $object->__toString();
        },
        AbstractObjectNormalizer::ENABLE_MAX_DEPTH => true,
        AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
            'date_publication' => $dateCallback,
            'date_maj' => $dateCallback,
        ],
        'groups' => $groups,
    ];

    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AttributeLoader());
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);
    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer]);


    $contentJSON = $serializer->normalize($global_content, 'json', $defaultContext);    

